# Where to farm the basic upgrade materials?

Tags: destiny

I've been playing destiny for about 2 months now, and even though I've managed to collect quite a few legendaries and a couple of exotics, I can't find good, reliable farming circuits to obtain the four basic materials.

I'm looking for circuits for:

**Spinmetal**

**Helium Filaments**

**Spirit Blooms**

**Relic Iron**

Videos or detailed instructions please. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a broad question. In my experience farming in any zone will do the job, you just have to make sure you find all the nooks and crannies were chests and nodes spawn.

Comment: This question is much better answered with videos than text. Just go to Youtube and search for "Destiny [material name] farming". There's no silver bullet here, there are multiple routes for every material. Otherwise, Lasse already wrote you a nice [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/196708/62507).
But my opinion - scince you can now buy mats with marks, farming is not as important as before.

Comment: Marks are way more valuable than basic mats based on the time it takes to earn them, when farming basic mats is easy.

Comment: Because your question about rare materials has all the routes for basic mats set out in it, making this question mute.

Comment: @DavidYell: Although that question has a very good answer it doesn't explicitly map out routes for all types so doesn't directly answer the question. Also (and I'm trying to educate here, not be a dick) I think you meant "moot", not "mute" - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moot